# Camel perform endpoint & route

Tags: xml, apache-camel, endpoint

I want to scan folder with subfolders, this is my configuration

```
Source

-- Center_A

  -- Target

-- Center_B

  -- Target
.....
```

My questions:

1. How to scan Source/Center* (without subfolders Target)
2. How to route files scanned in Source/Center_A in Source/Center_A/Target
   and route Source/Center_B in Source/Center_B/Target

My camel-context.xml

```
    <endpoint id="dossierin" uri="file:Source/Center*" />

     <route>
        <from ref="dossierin" />
        <to uri="${file:dossierin}/Target" />
    </route>
```

EDIT 1 :

First issue fixed

```
<endpoint id="dossierin" uri="file:Source?recursive=true&amp;maxDepth=1"/>
```

EDIT 2 :

Second issue fixed

```
<camelContext id="camelCtx" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <endpoint id="repoOutA" uri="file:work/outA" />
    <route>
        <from uri="file:Source?recursive=true&amp;maxDepth=2&amp;move=Target" />
        <to ref="repoOutA"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

The last problem, move option is sufficient I don't want to use

```
  <to ...>
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)
The file component allows to configure the min and max depth which you can use to limit to only scan down 2 levels deep (1=base dir, 2=first sub dir). And set the recursive=true as well.

See the documentation: http://camel.apache.org/file2

2) Dont understand your question.

Comment: In all folders Center_A, Center_B ... Center_X, i have a folder Target.
Considering foo.xml in Center_A, i want to route it to Center_A/Target
Considering toto.xml in Center_Y, i want to route it to Center_Y/Target
etc...

Comment: Use the move option. Read the documentation about it.